# Changing direction of the ball after collision

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-physics, collision, p5.js

I have written this code to demonstrate a basic visual p5js project. In here there are 10 balls of varying sizes and colors that spawn at random positions, move around in the canvas and might collide with each other. I am not looking for elastic collision or "realistic" collision physics for that matter. I just want the balls to change to a different direction (can be random as long as it works) and work accordingly.

Here is my code :

```
class Ball {
  //create new ball using given arguments
  constructor(pos, vel, radius, color) {
    this.pos = pos;
    this.vel = vel;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
  }
  //collision detection
  collide(check) {
    if (check == this) {
      return;
    }
    let relative = p5.Vector.sub(check.pos, this.pos);
    let dist = relative.mag() - (this.radius + check.radius);

    if (dist < 0) { //HELP HERE! <--
      this.vel.mult(-1);
      check.vel.mult(-1);
    }
  }

  //give life to the ball
  move() {
    this.pos.add(this.vel);

    if (this.pos.x < this.radius) {
      this.pos.x = this.radius;
      this.vel.x = -this.vel.x;
    }
    if (this.pos.x > width - this.radius) {
      this.pos.x = width - this.radius;
      this.vel.x = -this.vel.x;
    }
    if (this.pos.y < this.radius) {
      this.pos.y = this.radius;
      this.vel.y = -this.vel.y;
    }
    if (this.pos.y > height - this.radius) {
      this.pos.y = height - this.radius;
      this.vel.y = -this.vel.y;
    }
  }
  //show the ball on the canvas
  render() {
    fill(this.color);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.radius * 2);
  }
}

let balls = []; //stores all the balls

function setup() {
  createCanvas(window.windowWidth, window.windowHeight);
  let n = 10;
  //loop to create n balls
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    balls.push(
      new Ball(
        createVector(random(width), random(height)),
        p5.Vector.random2D().mult(random(5)),
        random(20, 50),
        color(random(255), random(255), random(255))
      )
    );
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  //loop to detect collision at all instances
  for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      balls[i].collide(balls[j]);
    }
  }
  //loop to render and move all balls
  for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].move();
    balls[i].render();
  }
}
```

Here is a link to the project : https://editor.p5js.org/AdilBub/sketches/TNn2OREsN

All I need is the collision to change the direction of the ball to a random direction and not get stuck. Any help would be appreciated. I am teaching kids this program so I just want basic collision, doesnot have to be "realistic".

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues you are currently encountering with balls being stuck has to do with randomly generating balls that overlap such that after one iteration of movement they still overlap. When this happens both balls will simply oscillate in place repeatedly colliding with each other. You can prevent this simply by checking for collisions before adding new balls:

```js
class Ball {
  //create new ball using given arguments
  constructor(pos, vel, radius, color) {
    this.pos = pos;
    this.vel = vel;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
  }
  
  isColliding(check) {
    if (check == this) {
      return;
    }
    let relative = p5.Vector.sub(check.pos, this.pos);
    let dist = relative.mag() - (this.radius + check.radius);
    return dist < 0;
  }
  
  //collision detection
  collide(check) {
    if (this.isColliding(check)) {
      this.vel.x *= -1;
      this.vel.y *= -1;
      check.vel.x *= -1;
      check.vel.y *= -1;
    }
  }

  //give life to the ball
  move() {
    this.pos.add(this.vel);

    if (this.pos.x < this.radius) {
      this.pos.x = this.radius;
      this.vel.x = -this.vel.x;
    }
    if (this.pos.x > width - this.radius) {
      this.pos.x = width - this.radius;
      this.vel.x = -this.vel.x;
    }
    if (this.pos.y < this.radius) {
      this.pos.y = this.radius;
      this.vel.y = -this.vel.y;
    }
    if (this.pos.y > height - this.radius) {
      this.pos.y = height - this.radius;
      this.vel.y = -this.vel.y;
    }
  }
  //show the ball on the canvas
  render() {
    fill(this.color);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.radius * 2);
  }
}

let balls = []; //stores all the balls

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  let n = 10;
  //loop to create n balls
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let newBall =
      new Ball(
        createVector(random(width), random(height)),
        p5.Vector.random2D().mult(random(5)),
        random(20, 40),
        color(random(255), random(255), random(255))
      );
    let isOk = true;
    // check for collisions with existing balls
    for (let j = 0; j < balls.length; j++) {
      if (newBall.isColliding(balls[j])) {
        isOk = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (isOk) {
      balls.push(newBall);
    } else {
      // try again
      i--;
    }
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  //loop to detect collision at all instances
  for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      balls[i].collide(balls[j]);
    }
  }
  //loop to render and move all balls
  for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].move();
    balls[i].render();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

---

That said, fully elastic collisions (which means collisions are instantaneous and involve no loss of energy due to deformation and resulting heat emission) are actually quite simple to simulate. Here's a tutorial I made on OpenProcessing demonstrating the necessary concepts using p5.js: [Elastic Ball Collision Tutorial](https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1174676).

Here's the final version of the code from that tutorial:

```js
const radius = 30;
const speed = 100;

let time;

let balls = []
let boundary = [];
let obstacles = [];

let paused = false;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    angleMode(DEGREES);
    ellipseMode(RADIUS);

    boundary.push(createVector(60, 4));
    boundary.push(createVector(width - 4, 60));
    boundary.push(createVector(width - 60, height - 4));
    boundary.push(createVector(4, height - 60));

    obstacles.push(createVector(width / 2, height / 2));

    balls.push({
        pos: createVector(width * 0.25, height * 0.25),
        vel: createVector(speed, 0).rotate(random(0, 360))
    });
    balls.push({
        pos: createVector(width * 0.75, height * 0.75),
        vel: createVector(speed, 0).rotate(random(0, 360))
    });
    balls.push({
        pos: createVector(width * 0.25, height * 0.75),
        vel: createVector(speed, 0).rotate(random(0, 360))
    });

    time = millis();
}

function keyPressed() {
    if (key === "p") {
        paused = !paused;
        time = millis();
    }
}

function draw() {
    if (paused) {
        return;
    }
    
    deltaT = millis() - time;
    time = millis();

    background('dimgray');

    push();
    fill('lightgray');
    stroke('black');
    strokeWeight(2);
    beginShape();
    for (let v of boundary) {
        vertex(v.x, v.y);
    }
    endShape(CLOSE);
    pop();

    push();
    fill('dimgray');
    for (let obstacle of obstacles) {
        circle(obstacle.x, obstacle.y, radius);
    }
    pop();

    for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
        let ball = balls[i];

        // update position
        ball.pos = createVector(
            min(max(0, ball.pos.x + ball.vel.x * (deltaT / 1000)), width),
            min(max(0, ball.pos.y + ball.vel.y * (deltaT / 1000)), height)
        );

        // check for collisions
        for (let i = 0; i < boundary.length; i++) {
            checkCollision(ball, boundary[i], boundary[(i + 1) % boundary.length]);
        }

        for (let obstacle of obstacles) {
            // Find the tangent plane that is perpendicular to a line from the obstacle to
            // the moving circle

            // A vector pointing in the direction of the moving object
            let dirVector = p5.Vector.sub(ball.pos, obstacle).normalize().mult(radius);

            // The point on the perimiter of the obstacle that is in the direction of the
            // moving object
            let p1 = p5.Vector.add(obstacle, dirVector);
            checkCollision(ball, p1, p5.Vector.add(p1, p5.Vector.rotate(dirVector, -90)));
        }
        
        // Check for collisions with other balls
        for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            let other = balls[j];
            
            let distance = dist(ball.pos.x, ball.pos.y, other.pos.x, other.pos.y);
            if (distance / 2 < radius) {
                push();
                let midPoint = p5.Vector.add(ball.pos, other.pos).div(2);
                let boundaryVector = p5.Vector.sub(other.pos, ball.pos).rotate(-90);
                
                let v1Parallel = project(ball.vel, boundaryVector);
                let v2Parallel = project(other.vel, boundaryVector);
                
                let v1Perpendicular = p5.Vector.sub(ball.vel, v1Parallel);
                let v2Perpendicular = p5.Vector.sub(other.vel, v2Parallel);
                
                ball.vel = p5.Vector.add(v1Parallel, v2Perpendicular);
                other.vel = p5.Vector.add(v2Parallel, v1Perpendicular);
                
                let bounce = min(radius, 2 * radius - distance);
                ball.pos.add(p5.Vector.rotate(boundaryVector, -90).normalize().mult(bounce));
                other.pos.add(p5.Vector.rotate(boundaryVector, 90).normalize().mult(bounce));
                
                pop();
            }
        }
    }

    // Only draw balls after all position updates are complete
    for (let ball of balls) {
        circle(ball.pos.x, ball.pos.y, radius);
    }
}

function drawLine(origin, offset) {
    line(origin.x, origin.y, origin.x + offset.x, origin.y + offset.y);
}

// Handles collision with a plane given two points on the plane.
// It is assumed that given a vector from p1 to p2, roating that vector
// clockwise 90 degrees will give a vector pointing to the in-bounds side of the
// plane (i.e. a "normal").
function checkCollision(ball, p1, p2) {
    let boundaryVector = p5.Vector.sub(p2, p1);
    let objVector = p5.Vector.sub(ball.pos, p1);
    let angle = boundaryVector.angleBetween(objVector);
    let distance = objVector.mag() * sin(angle);

    if (distance <= radius) {
        // Collision
        let vParallel = project(ball.vel, boundaryVector);
        let vPerpendicular = p5.Vector.sub(ball.vel, vParallel);

        ball.vel = p5.Vector.add(vParallel, p5.Vector.mult(vPerpendicular, -1));

        let bounce = min(radius, (radius - distance) * 2);
        // If the ball has crossed over beyond the plane we want to offset it to be on
        // the in-bounds side of the plane.
        let bounceOffset = p5.Vector.rotate(boundaryVector, 90).normalize().mult(bounce);
        ball.pos.add(bounceOffset);
    }
}

// p5.Vector helpers
function project(vect1, vect2) {
    vect2 = p5.Vector.normalize(vect2);
    return p5.Vector.mult(vect2, p5.Vector.dot(vect1, vect2));
}

function reject(vect1, vect2) {
    return p5.Vector.sub(vect1, project(vect1, vect2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Amazing solution. I was thinking on the same lines. But just one issue. It still gets stuck on some balls. Much more rare than my case but it does start that crazy vibration looping thingy. Especially when I increase the number of balls on the canvas. I also noticed if I increase the canvas width, then the problem gets reduced to some extend as there is more available are for the balls to move, I suppose. Any possible help?

Comment: I would guess that this is the result of the logic where when balls collide they simply reverse their direction, rather than bouncing of depending on their relative velocities and the direction of the impact. I could easily see multiple balls getting stuck in close proximity where instead of continuously colliding one with the other they are alternating between A colliding with B and B colliding with C, but that is just a guess. I would suggest switching to a better collision model as outlined in the tutorial.